# add to cart not working in tablet in magento-1.7

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 
Its working fine on my PC, but when i am using it from my tablet, Add to cart not working in tablet. 
What’s can be issue? 
Can anyone suggest?

Thanx in advance..

Comment: Can you give more details on the issue? I don't think simple "it's not working" is enough for someone to get started. Describe a little what is happening when you click 'add to cart'. A link to your website might be helpful also.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply.when i click to add to cart button, its not giving any error, but product is not adding in cart. there is not any error...this is ony in tablet and iphone

Answer (score 3):

I would start with some basic debugging on the device and see what you can get.

[Debugging Your Website on Mobile Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html)

Try to return some success messages or other values and log them to the JavaScript console with the `console.log()` command.

Also, try some server side debugging as well.  Use the built in debugging tools with Magento such as `Mage::log()`, and `Varien_Debug::backtrace()`.

You could hook some logs into the observer `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` and see what you get.

I hope this is a good start for you.  If you find out more, post them as comments above and we can get down to the bottom of your problem.